# date conversion from hhmmss to hhmm returns error in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, reporting-services, type-conversion

I have `StartTime` and `EndTime` columns in my SQL Server table which show as `hhmmss` (eg: `090000`)

I am looking to convert it to `9:30` using

```
 CONVERT(varchar(5), StartTime, 108) AS Start_Time, 
 CONVERT(varchar(5), EndTime, 108) AS End_Time
```

but I get an error:

> Conversion of varchar datatype to datetime datatype resulted in out-of-range value.

Any inputs?

Comment: What's your timezone?  You can use `IsDate()` to see if `StartTime` or `EndTime` are not valid dates as well.  What are the datatypes of starttime and endtime?

Comment: I don't currently see how that code can return that error message. You appear to be converting FROM a datetime data type TO a varchar(5), yet the error message says the opposite. Are you sure you're not trying to insert these values into a datetime field?

Comment: You really should leave formatting to the front end and return your data as the native type. I hope you are using the time datatype but I have a feeling you are not.

Comment: @Jon datatype is datetime

Comment: That's not what your error message says - there must be some misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use format function if your values are of datetime datatype.

```
FORMAT(StartTime, 'hhmm') AS Start_Time,
FORMAT(EndTime, 'hhmm') AS End_Time
```

Check example on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c343/1/0) and read more about [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx).

Comment: Yes, datatype is datetime. Any idea how I can use the same in sql query?

Comment: I have added example and link to msdn in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your time column has datatype int then you should try like below,

```
DECLARE @yourtime AS INT = '093000'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@yourtime ,1 ,0 ,REPLICATE('0' ,6- LEN(@yourtime))),3,0,':'),6,0,':'),108) AS Start_Time,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@yourtime ,1 ,0 ,REPLICATE('0' ,6- LEN(@yourtime))),3,0,':'),6,0,':'),108) AS End_Time
```

OR if you want to set it as SSRS expression you should try below,

```
=Format(Fields!StartTime.Value,"hh:mm")

=Format(Fields!EndTime.Value,"hh:mm")
```